# Dashing in Unity 3D Projects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, game-physics, game-engine

So I wanted to write a movement script for my player. I planned on creating something like a movement shooter. Therefore I thought I'd would be cool to add a dash-option (probably self explanatory). For whatever reason though the dash just wont work correctly, its more like a teleport.

So my approach was to just attach a "orientation"- emptyObject to the Player, get the .forward and .up * DashFactor and then just use rb.AddForce(dashForce, ForceMode.Impulse). I tried stuff like Acceleration or just Force but nothing worked. I kind of think that the problem lies in the way I calculate the running and stuff (what other option is there?). Since I saw this stuff in a tutorial it should look rather smooth and not some teleporting s***. I also have to crank up the DashFactor to even see a real result so I also thought about the gravitational pull? But since I never touched any option on the Rigidbody that doesnt seem quite plausible.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MovementController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Movement Input Values")]
    [SerializeField] float MovementSpeedFactor;
    [SerializeField] float JumpingFactor = 1;
    [SerializeField] float DashFactor = 1;
    [SerializeField] float DashFactorUp = 0;

    [Header("GameObjects")]
    [SerializeField] Transform test;
    Rigidbody rb;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float hInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float vInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");


        rb.velocity = new Vector3(hInput * MovementSpeedFactor, rb.velocity.y, vInput * MovementSpeedFactor);

     if(rb.velocity.y == 0)
        {
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector3(hInput * MovementSpeedFactor, 1f * JumpingFactor, vInput * MovementSpeedFactor);


            }
        }

      if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            Vector3 dashForce = test.forward * DashFactor + test.up * DashFactorUp;

            rb.AddForce(dashForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Possibly because in the next frame you overwrite the velocity.